# How does git tag --contains work?

Tags: git

Since a few days ago I've being trying to identify in which release -specified by a tag- an specific fix -specified by a commit- was deployed. Some posts here posted that `git tag --contains` is the way to gather this information, however [the documentation of the option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) seems obscure to me:

> --contains [commit]: 
>   Only list tags which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not specified).

From what I've being reading so far, a tag in git [is just a pointer to a specific commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), so it is not clear how a commit reference can "contain" another commit reference. Do you know how `git tag --contains` obtains the information it produces?

Comment: Indeed, it's not entirely sensible to use the word "contains" here.  A branch (the data structure formed within the DAG, as opposed to the name that points to the branch-tip commit) contains commits, but *commits* don't contain commits, and tags don't form branch-tips.  However, it's reasonable to extent the "contains" notion to mean "if this tag were also a branch tip, would the corresponding branch contain a given commit", which is how git defines the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so it is not clear how a commit reference can "contain" another commit reference

You can see more in the commit which introduced/enhanced this feature in git.
See:

- [commit 32c35cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32c35cfb1e9c8523b9d60e5095f1c49ebaef0279) (26 Jan 2009, git 1.6.0-rc2) by [Jake Goulding (`shepmaster`)](https://github.com/shepmaster).
  <sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster), 28 Jan 2009)</sup>
- [commit ffc4b80](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffc4b8012d9a4f92ef238ff72c0d15e9e1b402ed) (11 Jun 2011, git 1.7.6.3) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
  <sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster), 12 Jun 2011)</sup>

This was initially done through [git merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base), but:

> ### speed up `--contains` calculation
>
> When we want to know if commit `A` contains commit `B` (or any one of a set of commits, `B` through `Z`), we generally calculate the merge bases and see if `B` is a merge base of **A** (or for a set, if any of the commits `B` through `Z` have that property).
>
> When we are going to check a series of commits `A1` through `An` to see whether each contains `B` (e.g., because we are deciding which tags to show with "`git tag --contains`"), we do a series of merge base calculations. This can be very expensive, as we repeat a lot of traversal work.
>
> Instead, let's leverage the fact that we are going to use the same `--contains` list for each tag, and mark areas of the commit graph is definitely containing those commits, or definitely not containing those commits.
>   Later tags can then stop traversing as soon as they see a previously calculated
>   answer.

That was done through recursion, but...

See [commit cbc60b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbc60b67201e083a4970c8731c5382a575357e36) (24 Apr 2014, git 2.1.0-rc0) by [Jean-Jacques Lafay (`DontKnowPS`)](https://github.com/DontKnowPS).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster), 25 Apr 2014)</sup>

> ### `git tag --contains`: avoid stack overflow
>
> In large repos, the recursion implementation of `contains(commit, commit_list)` may result in a stack overflow. Replace the recursion with a loop to fix it.
>
> This problem is more apparent on Windows than on Linux, where the stack
>   is more limited by default. See also [this thread on the msysGit list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/msysgit/FqT6boJrb2g/discussion).

Answer (score 1):

When tag contains another commit, it means that this commit is one of its ancestors.