# Incorrect results returned by 'git tag --contains <commit>'

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

In [Linux kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/log/) repo, I am looking for tags containing a particular commit. Unfortunately, the results returned by the command `git tag --contains <commit>` is incorrect. It only shows a subset of tags.

I am looking for `tags` containing this commit: [`f991af3daabaecff34684fd51fac80319d1baad1`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=f991af3daabaecff34684fd51fac80319d1baad1). Its returning tags from `v4.13` to `v4.14-rc6`.

However, from manual analysis, I found that tags `v4.12.2` to `v4.12.14` also contain this commit. But these tags are not returned in the earlier list.

I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: After going through this very useful discussion on `--contains` calculation ([How does git tag --contains work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246615/how-does-git-tag-contains-work)). I guess this problem arises due to  [`cherry-picking`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html), where `git tag --contains` searches for `commit`  in newer `tags` and hence misses those older ones? I don't know whether my understanding is correct..

Comment: Try another command `git log v4.12.2 --pretty=%H | grep f991af3daabaecff34684fd51fac80319d1baad1`. If it returns `f991af3daabaecff34684fd51fac80319d1baad1`, then `v4.12.2` contains `f991af3daabaecff34684fd51fac80319d1baad1`. If Commit A is an ancestor/parent/itself of Commit B, then B contains A.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It returns nothing, so, I guess tag `v4.12.2` doesn't contain the commit `f991af3daabaecff34684fd51fac80319d1baad1`.  But, if I checkout tag `v4.12.2` (using, `git checkout tags/v4.12.2`), I can see the commit. I am bit confused here, if `f991af3daabaecff34684fd51fac80319d1baad1` is not a parent of tag `v4.12.2` commit, then how its possible to see the commit when I checkout  tag `v4.12.2`

Comment: Where do you see the commit after you check out `v4.12.2`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. what I meant was,  I can see the code changes in the relevant file (i.e, `ipc/mqueue.c`). It seems the patch is applied to the file for tags `v4.12.2` to `v4.14-rc6`. But, when I use the command `git tag --contains`, it only shows tags `v4.13` to `v4.14-rc6`

Comment: As you mention in your first comment, different commits can have the same or similar changes/diff. But `git tag --contains` searches only commits. It doesn't care about the actual changes.

Comment: This is the comment picked to the older version: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?h=v4.12.2&id=34bfc894734d56cca6c5924b5889e6308eeb66e1